# python: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python

I'm studying GUI programming with example code of simple gui program using PySide2. There are were 3 files in package:main, ui_functions, main_ui. And I added one more:app_functions. ui_functions and app_functions import MainWindow(which inherits QMainWindow) from main. like this.

```py
# main.py
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QFrame, QPushButton

# IMPORT FUNCTIONS
from ui_functions import *
from app_functions import *

# load gui
from main_ui import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        # apply UI
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # LOAD DEFINITIONS
        UIFunctions.uiDefinitions(self)
        
        UIFunctions.setButton1Name("button")
        # show main window - end
        self.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```py
# ui_functions.py
from main import MainWindow

from app_functions import *

class UIFunctions(MainWindow):
    def setButton1Name(self, text):
        self.ui.button1.setText(text)

    def uiDefinitions(self):
        self.ui.button1.clicked.connect(lambda: 
        self.APPFunctions.setButtonFunction())
```

```py
# app_functions.py
from main import MainWindow

# IMPORT FUNCTIONS
from ui_functions import *

class APPFunctions(MainWindow):

    def setButtonFunction(self):
        print("clicked")
```

```py
# main_ui.py
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QWidget, QFrame, QPushButton

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.resize(1000, 725)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.frame_main = QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.button1 = QPushButton(self.frame_main)
        self.button1.setObjectName(u"button1")
```

Before I add app_functions, there was no any import error. But after it was made, NameError has occured at import code of app_functions.
***NameError: name 'MainWindow' is not defined***

So I tried to clarify the location of main.py.

```py
from .main import *
```

And this time, ImportError has occured.

***ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package***

But the same code of ui_functions works well yet.
What would be changed for this code to work?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc
Sorry for the inappropriate example. But I have no idea with how to write proper gui example code yet. So I added guthub link.

Comment: I have not asked you for a link but an MRE, a link can be broken making your question useless.

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening here is that the class `MainWindow` also exists in `app_functions`, and with the star import method, the latter class is overriding the first one. If so, what you want to do is import classes by their name, such as:

```
from ui_functions import MainWindow
```

you can also import several classes in one line:

```
from package_name import Class1, Class2, Class3, ...
```

Comment: then it occurs another error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'MainWindow' from partially initialized module 'main' (most likely due to a circular import)